# Delete User defined security roles in SSRS

Tags: security, reporting-services, roles

I am trying to delete some roles I defined as SSRS security roles using SSMS. For whatever reason I am able to create new roles but does not allow me to drop them. The delete option is grayed out. Keep in mind that I opened SSMS as an administrator. That's why I was able to create a new one at the very beginning. I appreciate your help.

[image]

Comment: Does your administrator role have permission to delete roles?  Is there a user that is assigned that role that is currently using it?

Comment: Yes the administrator role has permission to delete/create roles. Thats why I was able to create it. There is also no user assigned to that role. Its just a new one created it and was trying to delete it right after 10 seconds. I was just doing a test.

Comment: Could you possibly show the properties page for this role?  At least, parts relevant to the role's permissions and set-up.

Comment: Just because you can create a role does not mean you can also delete it. You most likely do not have permissions to delete roles.